# Get value of data grid view first cell with context menu

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a data grid view populated with values. What I want to do is to right click item in data grid view, get a context menu to pop up, there I should select a menu item to get a first cell of selected row.
I managed to make context menu and its item, so I'm good there. What I need to do is to somehow get the value of first row while selecting said item.
I tried to use cell click method to get it and it works, but I have no clue how to implement it to menu item click.

```
string value = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: could you please post the code the the context menu pop up with the items, so that your propblem becomes easily reproducible. There should be another way than a workaround :)

Comment: there is nothing to post, I didn't code in my context menu, I used Context menu strip item from toolbox and then added it to data grid view events. That's about it. Unless i didn't fully understand your question?

Comment: yup, this was what I meant. Thanx for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I managed to play around the problem and solve it like that:
I got the value I needed with mouse down method and stored it in global variable like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if(hit.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            finalValue = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[hit.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

After I click the menu item i can manage the variable as I want. This is not the exact solution for the problem I described, but HEY , as long as it works right? Hope it will help someone.

Comment: by the way, finalValue is a global string i declared at the beginning of the program